# If $\|\cdot\|$ is a submultiplicative norm, when does $\|AB\| = \|A\| \|B\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

The question is the same as the title. If a more concrete example is required, consider the norm induced on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ by any vector norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $A, B \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ the only case I can think of where $\|AB\| = \|A\|\|B\|$ is $A = B = I$. Are there any others?

Edit: Considering the comments have brought about some good points regarding the possible scope, let me include the additional questions:

(1) If $\| A\| = \| B \| = 1$, when is it true that $\| AB \| = 1$?  This is obviously true for the identity and any unitary or rotational operator.

(2) If $\| A \| > 1$ and $\| B \| > 1$, when is it true that $\| AB \| > 1$?

@JMoravitz will now note that the TeX has been typeset in the One True Holy Kosher Way ;-P

Comment: $A = \mathrm{Id}$ has $\|AB\| = \|A\|\|B\|$ for any $B$, same for $B=  \mathrm{Id}$, no need for $A=B= \mathrm{Id}$.

Comment: As a typesetting suggestion, `\|A\|\|B\|` produces $\|A\|\|B\|$, making it more readable instead of $||A||||B||$.

Comment: Are you asking for examples that work for all such norms or examples for specific norms? For example, if the norm is induced by the Euclidean norm, then any rotation will have norm one, and hence so will the products.

Comment: @martini fine, but this is a trivial extension.

Comment: @copper.hat. General case. There are arbitrarily many specific cases by simply using unitary / rotational operators and rescaling the norm.

Comment: 1) Basically boils down to measuring the subspaces where $A$ and $B$ achieve their norm bound, then making sure the image of $B$'s subspace intersects nontrivially with $A$'s subspace.  For a general induced norm this is almost tautological.

Comment: @ErickWong: your suggestion sounds like a potentially fruitful path. Awesome! Is it possible to refer me to any text / literature which works with this approach? I have relatively little experience looking at operator norms from a measure theory perspective, and the tautology you mention is lost to my ignorance.

Comment: @ErickWong: What do you mean by $A$ achieving its norm bound?

Comment: @copper.hat The norm of $A$ can be defined as a supremum taken over the unit sphere: in a finite-dimensional $\mathbb R^n$ this sphere is compact, so the supremum (aka upper bound) should be achieved by a specific vector or set of vectors.  I haven't thought it through carefully but I would expect it to be the eigenspace corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $A^T A$ (i.e. singular value).

Comment: @ErickWong: The norm is not necessarily an induced norm. Take the Frobenius norm for example.

Comment: @copper.hat Sure, but the OP expressed an interest in the induced case.  If the norm is not induced, I'm not sure how meaningful this question is, since we could rescale the norm by an arbitrary constant and the comparison between $\|AB\|$ and $\|A\| \|B\|$ is silly since it's not a dimensionless scaling.

Comment: @ErickWong: I don't know what you mean by 'dimensionless scaling', but the fact that the norm is sub multiplicative reduces the possibilities for arbitrary scaling. I would not label it as silly.

Comment: There are lots of examples. E.g. the equality holds for any induced $p$-norm if $A$ or $B$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries have unit moduli; it holds for the operator norm if $A$ or $B$ is a unitary matrix; it holds for the induced $\infty$-norm if both $A$ and $B$ are row stochastic; it holds for the induced 1-norm if both $A$ and $B$ are column stochastic.

Comment: @JMoravitz definitely true, although I prefer $\|A\|\cdot\|B\|$ even more.